# How to copy & insert records in table by stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with one field: lngStatusID with value 2 for all the records.

Now I need to insert all the records again in the same table but with lngStatusID=1

So for that I think stored procedure will help me somehow.

AS per my logic it should be something like:

1) I need to read each record with loop

2) copy all fields in temporary variables

3) And than execute insert query to insert the record with lngStatusID=1

I am new to stored procedure.
So can any one guide me how to do that?

Or is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: So you have a table with a single field, multiple rows, and the same value for every row? That doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @Vikas The way you describe things show your background with procedural-type languages.  The insight is that with SQL, many things can be done in a declarative fashion.  The SQL language or extensions thereof allow for procedural statement/snippets which can either be used in stored-procedures or even in ad-hoc queries.  They are very useful in some cases, but do "think declaratively" first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure for this, a simple INSERT statement will do:

```
insert into mytable
(field1, field2, lngStatusID)
select field1, field2, 1
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO <TABLENAME> (Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, 2
FROM <TABLENAME>
```

No need for sp or cursors

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to insert them again? Maybe simple UPDATE will be enough?

```
UPDATE table SET IngStatusID = 1
```

Please provide more details, because for me it is pointless to copy all the records to temporary table to insert them again.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET IngStatusID = 1
```

That being said, any table with only one field probably shouldn't be a table unless its some kind of lookup.

Comment: Even if it was a lookup table, what would be the point of having a single column with the same value on multiple rows?

Comment: Agreed, there is no point to having the same value in multiple rows.

Comment: @JohnFx: multiple fields ("all fields") are mentioned in 2) in the original question.